# OpenShift access MySQL from another gear

Tags: mysql, node.js, openshift

I have two apps on OpenShift. 
One is running on a salable PHP gear with a MySQL cartridge. 
The other one is a node.js gear.

How can I access this MySQL database from node.js

Comment: Hi RahulRoy, Were you able to get this to work, I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @Ravi Yes. Copy the value of the database environment variable on the gear with the attached database and use it in your other gear. It worked.

Comment: Thanks Rahul. I tried that it did not work so there are are some hackish-work-arounds mentioned here https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202187184 , i will try them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your php application is scalable, then you can use the connection information from your PHP gear (ssh into your gear and run '`env | grep MYSQL`' to get that information) to connect to your MySQL gear from your node.js application.  Do not use the OpenShift environment variables as they will not be available to your node.js application.  Not that the MySQL Port number will not be the standard 3306, but another random port number, it is important that you use that information in your connection string.

Comment: Thanks Corey, can you give an example of a connection string? Do you have a link with more info on this on your website?

Comment: It does not seem to work: Do I still need additional paid gears as stated here: https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/nodejs-set-up-a-connection-to-mysql-created-in-the-php-app